# Calling ruby from shell

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell, sh

When I have an executable ruby script `foo` starting with a shebang

**foo**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

and call that ruby script from within a bash script `bar` as executable (i.e., not calling `ruby foo`, but directly `foo`), how can I get the full path of `bar` from within the ruby script `foo`?

---

**Edit**

If this is not possible, then is it possible if I have a bash script `baz` in between so that:

`bar` (bash) calls `baz` (bash) which calls `foo` (ruby)

where `bar` calls `baz` without any explicit argument and `baz` figures out the path of its caller `bar`, and passes that as an argument when calling `foo`?

For my purpose, it is okay whether or not `foo` needs to receive the path information as an argument as long as the original bash script `bar` does not need to pass that explicitly.

Comment: You have to pass on $0 as an argument when calling foo. If $0 is not good enough, have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/193892

Comment: @Prof.Falken I want to do that without explicitly passing such argument to `foo`.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. I mean, what would the mechanism be to transfer that information?

Comment: @Prof.Falken I am not sure. Is it possible if I have a bash script `baz`in between so that `bar` (bash) calls `baz` (bash) which calls `foo` (ruby) and let `bar` call` `baz` without `$0` or any other explicit argument but let `baz` figure that out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that the question is not well defined.  If `bar` is not a unique link to the executable, then there is no unique path.  Assuming you don't care about that issue and you just want to know how `bar` was accessed and if you are running on Linux that information is available in `/proc/pid-of-bar/cmdline`.  If foo's parent is the process running bar (it should be, unless you've daemonized or `foo` is not a direct descendant), the bar's pid is available to foo in the environment at PPID (although ruby almost certainly provides a better way to access the parent's pid.)  So, get your parent's pid and read /proc/parent-pid/cmdline.  If bar was invoked as a shell script, the first string of cmdline will be the interpreter (terminated by a null), and the second string will be the path you care about.

Comment: When `bar` has symbolic links, then I would want the realpath.

Comment: You want to look in `/proc/pid-of-bar/cmdline`

Comment: Okay, I can use `Process.ppid` to get the pid of the parent.

Comment: Responding to your first comment regarding symbolic links: I'm not talking about symbolic links.  If `/p/a/t/h/bar` and `/p/a/t/h/baz` and `/p/a/t/h/qux` are all (hard) links to the same script, then there is no unique "realpath" to the file: there are 3 different paths to the file.

Comment: Thanks for that. I don't have such links, so that would not be an issue. By the way, I followed and looked at the `cmdline` of the parent process. It says: `/bin/bash--noediting-i` Does this mean it does not have the path information?

Comment: How are you looking at the file?  That looks like an artifact of the tool you are using to view.  Try `tr \\000 \\n < /proc/.../cmdline`

Comment: In above, I was using a text editor to see it. When I did `tr ...`, it's still the same. The only difference is that `/bin/bash`, `--noediting`, and `-i` appear in different lines.

Comment: It looks like you are seeing the commandline of an interactive shell.  Perhaps bar invoked foo with exec, in which case it is no longer the parent.

Comment: When I call `bash bar`, then I can see something like `bash /path/to/bar` in `cmdline`. When I directly do `bar`, then I see `bash --editing -i`.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question $0 is all you need.

Edit: and of course pass this into your ruby script via the bar script.